# Safari: Is there a workaround for the Safari CSS print positioning bug?

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

For the latest versions of **Safari** for macOS (13.0.3) as well as for iOS (iOS 13.4.1), there’s a bug that affects CSS positioning of an object at the bottom of a page – but only for *printing*.

As an example, the following HTML code should obviously draw a green area at the bottom of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; height:100px; background-color: green;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Displaying this code as a web page in **Safari** works as expected. However, telling **Safari** to *print* that page results in the green area being at the *top* of the PDF printing preview (or the actual print) instead of the bottom (with only part of its height being visible at all).

Other browsers print as expected.

Positioning the area at the top of the page with `top:0px` produces no such problems in **Safari**, either; it’s only the positioning at the bottom where the printing problem occurs.

Is there any known workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
@media print {
          * {
              page-break-after: always;
          }
      }
```

```html
<div style="height: 100vh">
   <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; width: 100%; display: block; bottom:0px; page-break-after: always; height:100px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, now the green area is completely invisible in print …

Comment: If I add `page-break-after` directly to the inline CSS of the div, it changes nothing at all.